# Named exports in dart

Tags: dart, syntax

Is there any way to use named exports in dart?
For example I have 'my_types' library with this structure:

```
lib
|  outside.dart
my_types
|  lib
|  |  main.dart
|  |  models.dart
|  |  repositories.dart
```

Models and repositories contains some classes:

```dart
// models.dart
abstract class ModelA {}
abstract class ModelB {}
```

```dart
// repositories.dart
abstract class RepositoryA {}
abstract class RepositoryB {}
```

In main.dart I can export this files:

```dart
// main.dart
export 'models.dart';
export 'repositories.dart';
```

And import them in outside.dart:

```dart
// outside.dart
import 'package:my_types/main.dart' show ModelA, RepositoryB;

class ModelAImpl implements ModelA {};
class RepositoryBImpl implements RepositoryB {};
```

But with a lots of classes I will end up with huge mix of classes from models, repositories and other categories.

Is it possible to do something like

```dart
// main.dart
export 'models.dart' as models; // just a pseudocode. there is no 'as' statement for exports
export 'repositories.dart' as repositories;
```

to be able then to import them like this and keep some structure in this mess:

```dart
import 'package:my_types/main.dart' show models, repositories;

class ModelA implements models.ModelA {};
class RepositoryB implements repositories.RepositoryB {};
```

Comment: The code looks fine and it should work. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: ```export 'models.dart' as models;``` is not valid code. there is no 'as' statement for export directive. only for import

Comment: Dart does not have nested naming (like Java packages) so it is not possible to name an export since that would add confusion when importing (should we use the name from the export or the import? what happens with collisions of same named classes?). So in short, what you are requesting is not possible in current version of Dart.

Comment: maybe there is any other solution (without named exports) to be able to import code like this: ```import 'package:my_types/main.dart' show models, repositories;```?

Answer (score 1):

In dart there is no `as` keyword for exporting libraries. However you can control which elements to export using the `show` keyword.

Here's a [link](https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/create-library-packages#organizing-a-library-package) for reference

Comment: This was just a pseudocode to show an idea of what I want to achieve. The main goal is to be able to import with this syntax: ```import 'package:my_types/main.dart' show models, repositories;``` instead of ```import 'package:my_types/main.dart' show ModelA, RepositoryB;``` and accessing ModelA and RepositoryB with ```models.ModelA``` and ```repositories.RepositoryB```